# How can I create dynamic variable names without using a dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba, aspen

I am linking Excel with Aspen Hysys which allows me to import data from the second one. Hysys has a large hierarchy three of objects including the Stream object. The Stream object contains variables such Temperature, VaporFraction and so on and I access them through object syntax is like:

```
Dim hyApp As HYSYS.Application
Dim hyCase As HYSYS.SimulationCase
Dim hyStream As HYSYS.Streams
Dim temperature As Double

Set hyApp = CreateObject("HYSYS.Application")
Set hyCase = hyApp.ActiveDocument
Set hyStream = hyCase.Flowsheet.MaterialStreams.Item(0)
temperature = hyStream.TemperatureValue
```

Now if I need, the `VaporFraction`, I need to do the following:

```
Dim vaporFraction As Double
vaporFraction = hyStream.VaporFractionValue
```

But, what if I need other properties? Or need 100 properties?

Is there a way to convert strings (stored in cells) to variable names. I understand the concept of using dictionaries. But in this case, it will not work.

What I would expect is something like this:

```
properties = ("Temperature", "VaporFraction")
For Each property in properties
    createVaribleName(property + "Value")
Next property
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for Classes you can use the `CallByName` function. See here: [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/calling-a-property-or-method-using-a-string-name)

Returning a class property, example:

```
Dim MyCollection As Collection: Set MyCollection = New Collection
MyCollection.Add "A"
MyCollection.Add "B"
Debug.Print CallByName(MyCollection, "Count", VbMethod)
```

If you are working with code you wrote in a standard module, take a look at `Application.Run`.

Comment: OMG!!  I didn't have any hope of finding solution just today. Thanks. That's just what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. It's a little known feature to be sure, another little trick is that you can type `VBA.` in the VBA IDE and see what's included as part of the standard VBA library. This is packed in, but very easily missed.